# MySQL Import Issue

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8

I am trying do export a database from one database to another.  I am using the following commands to export and import:

```
export: mysqldump -u root -p dwad dwadallauth.sql
import: $ mysql -u root -p dwad < dwadallauth.sql
```

I then checked and it was evident the original database was created using:

```
CREATE DATABASE dwad CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

and then privileges were granted as follows:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dwad.* TO 'dwad'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '9LSo1SxqdJF45PL';
```

So I tried the following import:

```
import: $ mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 dwad < dwadallauth.sql
```

However, whenever I try to import I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 54: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
  `sent` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 ' at line 3
```

I have checked and the MySQL versions are as follows:

```
Export: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13, for Linux (armv7l) using  EditLine wrapper

Import: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.50, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

I hope someone may be able to point me in the right direction, many thanks in advance.

PS

Below is a copy of the SQL file created by the export:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.13, for Linux (armv7l)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: dwad
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `account_emailaddress`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account_emailaddress`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `account_emailaddress` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `primary` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `account_emailaddress_user_id_2c513194_fk_auth_user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_emailaddress_user_id_2c513194_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `account_emailaddress`
--

LOCK TABLES `account_emailaddress` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `account_emailaddress` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `account_emailaddress` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `account_emailconfirmation`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account_emailconfirmation`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `account_emailconfirmation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `sent` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `email_address_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `key` (`key`),
  KEY `account_ema_email_address_id_5b7f8c58_fk_account_emailaddress_id` (`email_address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `account_ema_email_address_id_5b7f8c58_fk_account_emailaddress_id` FOREIGN KEY (`email_address_id`) REFERENCES `account_emailaddress` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual for mysql 5.7:

> Downgrading more than one release level is supported using the logical downgrade method, but only if you downgrade one release level at a time. For example, you can downgrade from 5.7 to 5.6, and then to 5.5.

You are trying to go from 5.7 to 5.5 in one step. This might be causing your problem.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html

Comment: Upgrade to version 5.6 and it worked perfectly.  Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this in the future I found the following website useful:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/upgrade-mysql-5-5-to-5-6-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

`datetime(6)` is not supported in older versions.  You will have to lose the microseconds during the downgrade.

Comment: Clarification - `FRAC_SECOND` (with lots of limitations) existed until 5.5.3, when it was changed to `MICROSECOND`.  5.6.4 fractional seconds (microsecond) support in TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP.